# What is the most efficient way to initialise array of list with an empty list?

Tags: c#, optimization

I would like to initialise an array of List with empty List in the most efficient manner.

What is the correct way to do it ?

```
    List<int>[] neighbour = new List<int>[10]; // this does not create the List
    for (int i = 0 ; i < neighbour.Length ; ++i)
        neighbour[i] = new List<int>();        // is that really efficient ?
```

Comment: _"is that really efficient ? "_ Yes, it is. At least it is more efficient than using LINQ.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
var neighbour = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x=> new List<int>()).ToArray();
```

Comment: This will give you an array that contains ten references to the same empty list.  If you want ten independent empty lists, you'll need to create them (perhaps using `Enumerable.Range.Select`  or the like).

Comment: You're right, my original answer used Range. Thanks.

Comment: Your new answer won't compile ;)

Comment: The current version of your example does not compile.

Comment: But OP's way is still more effficient since `ToArray` has no knowledge of the size of the array.